# Set/adjust file version of a rtf-file with VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I created a logon script to automatically create a email signature for Outlook. This script creates the following file "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Default_signature.rtf"

I would like to add to a versionnumber to this file so I can check if an update of this file is necessary or not. If not, exit logon script. Else update signature with a higher versionnumber.

To get a versionnumber was pretty easy to find, but I couldn't find how to set/change a versionnumber with VBscript.

Using the DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties didn't work for me. I kept getting a ActiveX-error "Can't create object". It could be that I have to register
the dsofile.dll in the system but this code has to work for every user in our company and I don't want to install this on every device before I can use this logon script.

```
'Code for requesting versionnumber    
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    file = "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Default_signature.rtf"
    Wscript.Echo "Version = " & objFSO.GetFileVersion(file)
```

I hope someone could tell me how to do this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know DSO is the only supported way by Microsoft to change properties of the files without rewriting them. There are some VBA scripts out there for Excel, but that does not apply in your case with RTFs.

However, might i suggest a different alternative? I have in my infrastructure a script that is placed to run at each logon and checks on a share a certain file's last modified date. If the file present on the machine is older, then it's replaced by that on the share.

```
 Dim objFSO, strFileName

    strFileName = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tests\fdsfsd.rtf"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

    WScript.Echo objFSO.GetFile( strFileName ).DateLastModified

    Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to be the only available option I have...